# Display multiple calculated values in a table - R

Tags: r

I have the following calculated values stored in seven different variables.
Now I want them to display in an R output as follows.
How I can achieve this?
(The following table was created with markdown) assigning values to the data frame and printing it does not give my intended results. I am looking for more "cleaner" table.

| mean_reg | standard_deviation | minimum | First_quartile | median | third_quartile | maximum | iq_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31.10846 | 7.996179 | 2.5 | 27.92578 | 29.73158 | 33.85013 | 55.5 | 5.92435 |

Comment: bind all together in a data.frame with `df <- data.frame(mean_reg, standard_deviation, minimum,etc,etc..)` then `print(df)` or use one of the solutions of the above link

Comment: printing data frame adds other meta data to be displayed in the output as well. I want a cleaner tale for a report.

Comment: your question is incoherent. What do you mean by cleaner methods?

Comment: Here a list of packages that help formatting tables for output https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/table-other.html

Answer (score 0):

With `data.frame`:

```
mean_reg <- 31.10846
standard_deviation <- 7.996179
minimum <- 2.5
First_quartile <- 27.92578
median <- 29.73158
third_quartile <- 33.85013
maximum <- 55.5
iq_range <- 5.92435

df <- data.frame(mean_reg,standard_deviation,minimum,First_quartile,median,third_quartile,maximum,iq_range)
```

output:

```
> df
  mean_reg standard_deviation minimum First_quartile   median third_quartile maximum iq_range
1 31.10846           7.996179     2.5       27.92578 29.73158       33.85013    55.5  5.92435
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I am looking for more cleaner table to be published in a report.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All for the comments. I found that "kableExtra" package can be used to get a cleaner result as i intended.

```
mean_reg <- 31.10846
standard_deviation <- 7.996179
minimum <- 2.5
First_quartile <- 27.92578
median <- 29.73158
third_quartile <- 33.85013
maximum <- 55.5
iq_range <- 5.92435

    df <- data.frame(mean_reg,standard_deviation,minimum,First_quartile,median,third_quartile,maximum,iq_range) %>% kbl() %>% kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria")
```